# LinkedIn Ad Analytics: Downstream service returned an empty response for URN

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform's Ad Analytics API, specifically the [Analytics Finder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#analytics-finder).

The `pivot` parameter accepts various values. When using `pivot=COMPANY` I am able to successfully use response decoration to pull the organization directly from the `pivotValue` field with the following query parameter: `projection=(elements*(pivotValue~))`

However, when using `pivot=CAMPAIGN` or `pivot=CAMPAIGN_GROUP` or `pivot=CREATIVE` the response is always the same even though I can verify that the `pivotValue` field is clearly defined:

```
{'pivotValue!': {'message': 'Downstream service returned an empty response for URN.', 'status': 404}, 'pivotValue': 'urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:<SOMEID>'}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue when trying to retrieve campaign names through projection. I tried many solutions, until I found out that the issue happens when you filter by more than one account, like so:

```
?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&timeGranularity=DAILY
&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:12345678&accounts[1]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:01234567
&projection=(*,elements*(dateRange(*),clicks,impressions,pivot,pivotValue~(name)))
&fields=dateRange,clicks,impressions,pivot,pivotValue
&daterange_filter_logic
```

Apparently their backend doesn't support decoration for multiple accounts. As soon as you filter by **one** account, it works. My solution is to make separate requests for each account instead.